# How to save a resultSet and show all data in TableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, fmdb

I am using FMDB for my application and now I want to show my resultSet in TableView.
Here is some code-

```
    func getUser() {

    sharedInstance.database!.open()

    var resultSet: FMResultSet! = sharedInstance.database!.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM user_info", withArgumentsInArray: nil)

    if(resultSet != nil)  {
        while resultSet.next() {
           .
           . 
           .

        }
    }
```

Now here are many users in resultSet.Where and How can I put the results from resultSet so that I can show them in my TableView afterwards?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are iterating through the FMResultSet, it moves to the next row so you can do the below to save an array of your User objects

```
    let resultSet:FMResultSet! = FMResultSet()
    if (resultSet != nil) {
        var users:Array<User> = Array<User>()
        while (resultSet.next()) {
             let user:User = User()
             user.Id = resultSet.intForColumn("user_id")
             user.name = resultSet.stringForColumn("user_name")

             users.append(user)
        }
   }
```

// Now you have your users array here and you can reload its data into your UITableView as you want.

Comment: There you go, I modified it

Comment: Please check if it helped, mark it as an answer, if not tell me

Comment: That gave me the idea...but can you tell me how can I show the values one by one in the TableView?And Thanks for the help

Comment: In addition,I have my custom list,I just have to show the values from the array